# where can I find man page for top

Tags: command-line, documentation

I have a bugreport file containing output from (as it says)

```
top -n 1 -d 1 -m 30 -t
```

The -m option is not known on my ubuntu linux, wo where can I find the android man page for the top command? I don't have root access to my android device.

Answer (score 1):

By browsing the source code (for example [here](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/system/core/toolbox/top.c#565)) you can see the usage help:

```
static void usage(char *cmd) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -m max_procs ] [ -n iterations ] [ -d delay ] [ -s sort_column ] [ -t ] [ -h ]\n"
                    "    -m num  Maximum number of processes to display.\n"
                    "    -n num  Updates to show before exiting.\n"
                    "    -d num  Seconds to wait between updates.\n"
                    "    -s col  Column to sort by (cpu,vss,rss,thr).\n"
                    "    -t      Show threads instead of processes.\n"
                    "    -h      Display this help screen.\n",
        cmd);
}
```

As you can see, the -m option specifies the maximum number of processes to display.